# Creating a makefile C using all, clean, and other

Tags: c, makefile

My professor gave me a code that he already wrote and we had to fill in the rest. Now our task is to create a makefile using multiple targets. These are the directions:

"3. Create a Makefile to create your project. Your makefile should have the following targets (put all at the top)

a.).all Creates all object files and executable files

b.).Wall.o Builds the Wall.o object file from Wall.c

c.).Maze.o Builds the Maze.o object file from Maze.c

d.).DisjointSetADT.o Builds theDisjointSetADT.o object file from DisjointSetADT.c

e.).MazeBuilder.o Builds the MazeBuilder.o object file fromMazeBuilder.c

f.).MazeBuilder Builds the MazeBuilder executable from all object files

g.).clean Deletes all object files and executable files."

This is what I have so far:

```
all: MazeBuilder

Wall.o: Wall.c
    gcc -c -Wall Wall.c

Maze.o: Maze.c
    gcc -c -Wall Maze.c

DisjointSetADT.o: DisjointSetADT.c
    gcc -c -Wall DisjointSetADT.c

MazeBuilder.o: MazeBuilder.c
    gcc -c -Wall MazeBuilder.c

MazeBuilder: MazeBuilder.o Wall.o Maze.o DisjointSetADT.o 
    gcc MazeBuilder.o Wall.o Maze.o DisjointSetADT.o -o MazeBuilder

clean:
    rm -f *.o MazeBuilder
```

I have no idea why my auto grader says the makefile doesn't work.  There are tabs under each target already, not sure why they are not popping in when I copy my code over.

Comment: For starters: put build targets and dependencies on one line, and the build instructions on the next, indented with a TAB. No idea what you mean by the $-c stuff.

Comment: sorry will repost dont know why those character are there

Comment: That makefile is not **in** C.

Comment: Should work. Try to build locally

Comment: The error i get is that mazebuilder isnt being built properly

Comment: Post the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: "Mazebuilder wasn't built properly. Your Makefile fail to work." and "Wall.c and Wall.c fail to work."...

Comment: What happens when you try to execute your makefile, without involving the auto-grader?

Comment: I can't figure out how to do that and everytime I turn it in the error comes from the line under clean:

Comment: I just tried to compile in my terminal and the error i get says "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."

Comment: What is the name of the file you posted the contents above from?  What is the command you're invoking to start make?  A makefile must be named either `Makefile` or `makefile`, or else if you want to name it something different you have to tell make what you called it, with the `-f` option: `make -f mymakefile` (but probably the auto-grader will just run `make`, so you should name it either `Makefile` or `makefile`).

Comment: Also option n is your friend while developing: `make -n`

Answer (score 1):

We must proceed in small steps.

Start in a directory that contains the various source files (`Wall.c`, `DisjointSetADT.c` and so on) and the makefile. **This is essential.**

1) Compiling from the command line. Try this command (in the command line, instead of "make"):

```
gcc -c -Wall Wall.c
```

This should build `Wall.o`; if it doesn't then tell us (in a comment to this Answer) exactly what the result was. If it works, remove `Wall.o` and proceed to...

2) Compiling with Make. Try this:

```
make Wall.o
```

This should do exactly the same thing as step 1. If it works, try `make clean` to remove `Wall.o`.

3) Build all the object files:

```
make MazeBuilder.o Wall.o Maze.o DisjointSetADT.o
```

4) Linking the objects by hand:

```
gcc MazeBuilder.o Wall.o Maze.o DisjointSetADT.o -o MazeBuilder
```

5) The whole shebang:

```
make clean
make MazeBuilder
```

6) Using the default rule:

```
make clean
make
```

Tell us where and how this sequence fails, and we'll try to fix it.